# php site much slower after moving to https

Tags: php, performance, https

I have developed a large PHP tool for a client, running on a server that recently moved to HTTPS. On the same server, several other tools run (like wordpress and joomla) which aren't impacted speedwise by the move to HTTPS, but my script is.

As it is a pretty large script that I've developed, I am not sure what to look into first. What are likely things that may affect the speed of the pages?

Comment: What does your script do....?

Comment: bad scripts, bad DB design/ queries, lots of open DBconnections, wrong template design, weak servers,  lots of requests,  heavy images, slower bandwith of the users and so on ......

Comment: Please describe your php tool itself, your environment (server operating system, webserver, php ecosystem etc.).!

Answer (score 0):

For a script the main problem link to https is the number of consecutive connections you made. Make sure to set the options to reuse https connetions to avoid the handshake time.